# Change the value of a parameter annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Is there any way in Java to modify an annotation of a method parameter?

In this case, I would like modify the content of `theKey` (currently: `CHANGE_ME`) to something new (e.g. `I'M CHANGED`).

```
@ClassAnnotation(foo = "bar")
public interface SomeInterface {

    @MethodAnnotation(foo = "bar")
    void getDomains(@ParamAnnotation(theKey = "CHANGE_ME") String theString);

}
```

As far as I found out with runtime debugging, `getAnnotations()` in [Parameter.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/455d2e7cea03424717faf3826221213f30eca26d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.java#L357) finally leads to `sharedGetParameterAnnotations()` in [Executable.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/455d2e7cea03424717faf3826221213f30eca26d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/Executable.java#L558) which parses some `parameterAnnotations` ByteArray and then constructs an `Annotation`.

If I'm not mistaken, this would mean, that modifying the value of `@ParamAnnotation`'s `theKey` is not possible (unless messing around with the byte code - which is probably even more ugly then changing stuff with Reflection).

On the other side, this seems to be strange as changing values for `foo` in `@ClassAnnotation` and `@MethodAnnotation` works fine.

Comment: What's your end goal? Can't you do this in the thing processing the annotation?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The thing processing the annoation is actually JAX-WS. So, unfortunately, no :-)

Comment: jax-ws only processes your class once, doesn't it and that it on application start. So you'd need to change that annotation *before* jax-ws is started

Comment: Let's ignore JAX-WS for now, and focus on the question: Is there a way to modify a **parameter** annotation? Unfortunately, the linked question does not answer this, but only how to modify a **class** annotation (also works for **method** annotations, but not for **parameter annotations**)

Comment: All annotations behave the same. It's unclear what you mean by _works fine_. Please provide an example of what you did for those that didn't work for the parameter annotation.